# Non destructive installation : Ubuntu 13.10 -> Debian 7.2

Tags: ubuntu, debian, system-installation

How to make a non destructive installation of Debian 7.2 over Ubuntu 13.10 ?

Comment: define "non-destructive".

Comment: What do you want to not destroy? the root? usr? var? home? Are you currently using LVM? Are you willing to commit any external storage to the task?

Comment: Furthermore, if you cannot _make a non destructive installation of Ubuntu 13.10 over Ubuntu 13.10_, you may not be ready yet to _make a non destructive installation of Debian 7.2 over Ubuntu 13.10_.

Comment: Meaning retaining all the applications and data in /home after moving to another OS.

Comment: You should save `/etc` & `/home` and before of that save your installed packages with `dpkg -l > /home/user/debpackages.txt`. Then you should safely start a new installation.

Comment: So If I merge the new /etc folder with the old /etc folder, will the applications which were merged be recognised by the new system's package manager ?